# Why does $('someObject').attr("id")[0] not work in IE?

Tags: jquery

The following jquery code works in firefox, but is returning undefined in IE:

```
$('someObject').attr("id")[0]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
$('someObject').attr("id").charAt(0)
```

The [] indexer operator is not supported on strings in Internet Explorer. string::charAt() is the correct method to use.